Minimum number of oracle call to solve Simon problem by a (NDTM) non-deterministic Turing machine?
Simon's problem is a computational problem used to demonstrate an oracle separation between BQP and BPP classes.

It is known that the minimum number of oracle calls to be made by the BQP machine is $\Omega(n)$.

For the BPP machine, the lower bound of the oracle call is $\Omega(2^{n/2})$.


My query: I am trying to find a lower bound on the number of Oracle calls to be made by an NP machine to solve Simon's problem.
My attempt: I estimate two calls to the Oracle are sufficient for the NDTM machine to solve the problem.
Step I: NDTM guess the string $s\in \{0,1\}^n$.
Step II: NDTM calls the oracle at any $x\in_{R} \{0,1\}^n$ and note down the oracle output $f(x)$.
Step III: Again, NDTM calls the oracle at $x+s$ and notes down the oracle output $f(x+s)$. Then it checks if indeed $f(x)=f(x+s)$. If yes, then declare string $s$ as the answer.

Is the above argument correct?

Can the minimum number of Oracle queries be reduced to one?



No, your argument is not correct. A possible value of $s$ is $0^n$ (indeed, the decision version of Simon's problem is to distinguish $s=0^n$ from $s\ne0^n$, hence thus value is important).
Thus, your algorithm must be ready to guess $0^n$ as a potential value of $s$. But as you can see, whenever the algorithm guesses $0^n$, it will always accept and output this value as $f(x)=f(x\oplus0^n)$ no matter what, even if the actual value of $s$ is different!
In order to positively verify the $s=0^n$ case, an NP machine has to certify that the function is one-to-one rather than two-to-one. It needs an exponential number of queries to do that.
More precisely, any nondeterministic machine solving the problem, or even just its decision version (with $s=0^n$ being the YES instances, and $s\ne0^n$ the NO instances), must make at least $2^{(n+1)/2}$ oracle queries. This can be proved by a simple adversary argument:
First, set the oracle to the identity function $f(x)=x$. Then the NP machine much accept and output $s=0^n$ on some computation path $P$.
Let $X\subseteq\{0,1\}^n$ be the set of oracle calls made on $P$, and assume for contradiction that $|X|<2^{(n+1)/2}$. Since there are $\le\binom{|X|}2+1\le|X|^2/2<2^n$ elements in the set $\{x\oplus y:x,y\in X\}$, we can choose $s\in\{0,1\}^n\smallsetminus X$. We define a new oracle $g$ as follows: for each pair of elements $\{x,x\oplus s\}$, we define $f(x)=f(x\oplus s)\in\{x,x\oplus s\}$ in some way, making sure that $f(x)=x$ for $x\in X$. (We can do that because by the choice of $s$, it cannot happen that both $x$ and $x\oplus s$ belong to $X$.)
Then if we run the machine with oracle $g$, $P$ is still an accepting path that outputs “$s=0^n$”, as $g\supseteq f\restriction X$; but this value is different from the actual $s$.
On the other hand, it is possible to solve the problem even deterministically using $O(2^{n/2})$ oracle queries (and overall running time $2^{n/2}n^{O(1)}$). The algorithm is as follows:

Query $f(x)$ for all $x$ in the sets $X=\{0,1\}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\times\{0\}^{\lceil n/2\rceil}$ and $Y=\{0\}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\times\{0,1\}^{\lceil n/2\rceil}$.

If $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ other than $x=y=0^n$, then output $s=x\oplus y\ne0^n$.

Otherwise, output $s=0^n$.



I totallly agree with your point mentioned in the first paragraph of your above answer. The two cases for $s\neq0^n$ and $s=0^n$ need to be distinguished as the key task for the decision problem.

doesn't it imply this oracle also separates the class BQP and NP in relativized worls. As the minimum number of query to be made by NP machine is superplynomial. // Kindly let me know if it is correct to infer this.

Yes, it shows that relativized BQP is not contained in relativized NP.
